# TSQL Where Clause Meeting Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I have a basic select query that is pulling in the results of a queue to our page. I am trying to add in some logic to the `where` clause that prevents records from showing when they contain a specific set of values.

```
WHERE (
        (L.requestType <> 'Check')
        AND (L.requestStatus <> 'New Request')
        AND (DATEDIFF(hour, CAST(L.requestDate AS DATE), GETDATE()) between 0 and 48)
      )
```

In the example above, I don't want to include records that have all three data points.

When doing some testing, it is excluding All "Checks" for example even though those records do not also meet the other two pieces of criteria.

How can I go about making my `where` clause meet all criteria and not do what appears to be an `or`?

Comment: It is not clear to me what criteria implies that you want to keep the rows and what criteria should be filtered.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - All data would be included except records that meet all three pieces of criteria in the where clause. They cant be checks that have a status of new request that are within the last 48 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
WHERE NOT (L.requestType = 'Check'
           AND L.requestStatus = 'New Request'
           AND (DATEDIFF(hour, CAST(L.requestDate AS DATE), GETDATE()) between 0 and 48
          )
```

which is equivalent to

```
WHERE (L.requestType <> 'Check'
       OR L.requestStatus <> 'New Request'
       OR DATEDIFF(hour, CAST(L.requestDate AS DATE), GETDATE()) not between 0 and 48
       )
```

Comment: That did it :x - Thanks for the quick response. Had never thought about trying that before.